# Reverse routing on an application deployed in a Tomcat context

Tags: rest, playframework

I am developing a Play 1.2.5 application that will be installed in a Tomcat context:

```
http://mytomcat:8080/myapp
```

And in my routes file I have:

```
GET     /companies/{companyID}/employees    Employees.getForCompany
```

As per the instructions for deploying a Play application in a Tomcat context, I am generating URLs exlusively using the Reverse Router. This works fine, but I am not sure what to do in the case of a jQuery method such as an Ajax request of this style:

```
var companyID = $('#companies').find(":selected").val();
$.ajax({
    url : "@{Employees.getForCompany(companyID)}",
    ...
});
```

Obviously the value of companyID isn't known at the time of the generation of the HTML and the resolution of routes by the reverse router.

The only solution that I can see is to reconfigure my `routes` file so that the URLs are different and the parameters are always at the end, but that makes the REST URLs less logical.

```
GET     /companies/employees/{companyID}    Employees.getForCompany
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution myself - Play includes the `jsAction` tag which generates a function that builds the correct URL:

```
var companyURL = #{jsAction @Employees.getForCompany(':companyID') /}
$.ajax({
    url : companyURL({companyID:companyID}),
    ...
});
```

Like that I can maintain the preferred routes mapping:

```
GET     /companies/{companyID}/employees    Employees.getForCompany
```